# Checking against null with overloaded == operator in Dart?

Tags: dart, null, operator-overloading, equals

I have overloaded the `== operator` in Dart and would like to use it to check against `null` explicitly, is there any way of achieving this?

As I understand it, what happens is that Dart implicitly checks against `null` even when you overload the equals operator. It determines that `thing` is not `null` but rather an instance of `Overridden` and therefore `thing == null` returns `false`.

I understand that this is very much the desired behavior as the overloaded function can't be called if the object has not yet been initiated, but is there a way to create a static operator overload or some other way of implementing the null check explicitly?

```
class Overridden {
  final dynamic _value;

  Overridden({value}) : _value = value;

  @override
  bool operator ==(other) => _value == other.value;

  dynamic get value => _value;
}

void main() {
  Overridden thing = Overridden();

  // Prints null as expected
  print(thing.value);
  // Prints false, which is unexpected
  print(thing == null);
}
```

I would like to be able to make the null determination myself directly using the `==` operator without using a getter or checking against `Overridden()`.

Comment: Even if you could do it, it seems like it would be a bad idea since it would violate what everything else considers to be object equality, commutativity could never work (`null == thing` would be different from `thing == null`), and possibly would run afoul of `hashCode` rules (objects that compare equal should produce the same hash code).

You instead could have a special sentinel instance to check against (e.g. `thing == const thing.invalid()`) or add your own custom method (e.g. `thing.isNull()`).

Comment: Yes, I currently am using  `thing.isNull()` and it seems like it's the best way to go about it. The only reason I would have liked to be able to check against null directly is because I have a validator function that checks if a value is [truthy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) and thought it would have been elegant to not have to check whether an isNull function exists, but as you pointed out it's probably not a good idea for various reasons.